# Ajax form upload with text input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file, upload

I'm trying to submit a form with several file
uploads using ajax with input text.
If the user have uploaded all the
files using ajax but forget to enter his 
name and the form re-populate again. How do 
i tell the user that he has already uploaded
these  files

```
<input type=file id=file1 name=file1 />

<input type=file id=file2 name=file2 />

<input type=text id=name name=name />
```

The form reload showing error message that 
the **name has not being enter**. How do i tell the 
user that the file1 has already being uploaded.
Technology(PHP)

Thanks

Comment: We don't know how you are processing the uploaded files server-side but I believe you are storing them in a database. Why don't you query the database to know if the user has uploaded that file?

Comment: ok. if the user has uploaded the file what next. do i deactivate the upload button or show some other success button

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing code that:
1. When the form is activated, check what is there and what isn't.
2. Cache that data into cookies
3. Do uploading code
4. Upon reloading the form, check cookies for what was entered and what wasn't.
5. Display an alert/message to tell them what they entered and what is still needed.